# Creating Recursive Sequences

Tags: function-construction, recursion

Quite a simple question, I reckon, however, even quite an extensive search hasn't helped me.

I want to define a recursively defined sequence that starts with defined `f[1]` and `f[2]` and distinguishes the input like so: `f[3k]`, `f[3k+1]`, `f[3k+2]`. Each of these would have its own expression.

For further clarification, an example:
$$  f(3n) = f(n)+1 $$
$$  f(3n+1) = f(n)+2 $$
$$  f(3n+2) = f(n)+3 $$
How does one go about that? I do know how to write simple recursion formulas on the level of Fibonacci or a factorial, it's only the distinguishing the input part. Also, this should be possible without any `if` statements, etc.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define an expression for each such pattern, using `Condition` (shorthand: `/;`) to specify that it should only match in the appropriate cases. I'm assuming by `f[3k]` you mean some input that's fully divisible by `3`, so I'd write:

```
f[1] = 0;
f[2] = 0;
f[x_] /; Mod[x, 3] === 0 := {"3k def",f[x-1]}
f[x_] /; Mod[x - 1, 3] === 0 := {"3k def",f[x-1]}
f[x_] /; Mod[x - 2, 3] === 0 := "{"3k def",f[x-1]}

f[6]
(* {"3k def", {"3k+2 def", {"3k+1 def", {"3k def", 0}}}} *)
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, however, this looks like it should be the solution! Thanks, I shall try that now and then report.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!